# Getting Error with "from_raster" attribute in pysheds

Tags: python, attributeerror

This is my first time asking a question. I am trying to use "pysheds" to analyze some hydrologic DEM files. The developer as some pretty thorough "how to" videos but when I try to load the DEM file in the way that they show I get the following error:

module 'pysheds.grid' has no attribute 'from_raster'

here's my code

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.colors as colors
    import geopandas as gpd
    import pysheds
    import pysheds.grid as Grid
    import mplleaflet
    
    grid = Grid.from_raster('path.tif', data_name = 'dem')`
```

I checked the `print(dir(Grid))` in the console and didn't see this attribute listed.

Am I missing something?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://github.com/mdbartos/pysheds), you should import `Grid` from `pysheds.grid` like this:

```
from pysheds.grid import Grid

grid = Grid.from_raster('n30w100_con', data_name='dem')
grid.read_raster('n30w100_dir', data_name='dir')
grid.view('dem')
```

instead of

```
import pysheds.grid as Grid
```